# Declaring a scalar value for a date parameter

Tags: sql-server, date, parameters

I am trying to set a value for a 2 parameters in SQL:

```
@DateLoading
@DateLoading2
```

I declare them as datetime:

```
DECLARE @DateLoading AS datetime
DELCARE @DateLoading2 AS datetime
```

In the `WHERE` clause I set the parameters as following:

```
WHERE
    o.DateLoading >= @Datetoloading AND
    o.DateLoading < @Datetoloading2 AND
```

I have problem setting the scalar value. I've tried with this code, but the error is the same:

```
SET @DateLoading = COALESCE(CASE WHEN @DateLoading = 'Current Month' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) ELSE NULL END,
                            CASE WHEN @DateLoading = 'Previous Month' THEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) ELSE NULL END,
                            CASE WHEN @DateLoading = 'Previous 7 Days' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, 6, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) ELSE NULL END,
                            DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
        );

SET @DateLoading2 = COALESCE(
    CASE WHEN @DateLoading2= 'Current Month' THEN DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0) ELSE NULL END,        
    CASE WHEN @DateLoading2= 'Previous Month' THEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0) ELSE NULL END,
    CASE WHEN @DateLoading2= 'Previous 7 Days' THEN DATEADD(HOUR,6,DATEADD(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()),0)) ELSE NULL END,
        GETDATE() 
)
```

Here is the error messages:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
> Must declare the scalar variable "@TimePeriod".
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
> Incorrect syntax near 'E'

Yes, you were right. I got rid of [S, [E]... (I wanted them to be alias) but I got rid of them... Also, the second mistake was `@TimePeriod`... I changed it to `@DateLoading`... But now, there is only 1 error message:

> Conversion failed when converting data and/or time from character string

The client should enter Start Date and End Date so as to receive results. But the code I have for setting the scalar value for these two parameters is totally wrong.

Comment: So where are you declaring and assigning `@TimePeriod` in your code? Is `[S], [E]` supposed to be a *column alias*? Get rid it's not needed here.

Comment: You can't use `@DateLoading` to hold both a `DATETIME` and `VARCHAR` somehow, so `SET @DateLoading = ..CASE WHEN @DateLoading = 'String value' then <DATETIME value>` makes no sense. I suspect you do need `@TimeLoading`, it's just not declared or passed. Ideally, you don't want to do this kind of logic in your SQL at all -- just have the client pass the range parameters as `DATETIME` values, and any logic for turning `Previous Month` into a pair of `DATETIME` values should be implemented there.